# How to solve the memory error while taking images using MATLAB?

Tags: image, matlab, memory

I am getting the following error(refer to the attached) while grabbing image data. How can this be resolved?

I tried using Mathworks suggested commands(imaqreset and imaqmex('feature','-limitPhysicalMemoryUsage',false);) but didn't help.

Let me know if you have other ideas.

Thanking You.

[image: Error in MATLAB]

Comment: "insufficient free physical memory". The solution is to either buy more memory, or load fewer images in memory. If you think this is an issue with your code, you should post your code (or rather, a minimal version of it, see [mre]).

Comment: My colleagues have sometimes run across the above 'type' of error when just doing basic MATLAB calculations. I have found that these colleagues often never completely exit MATLAB or turn off their computers.

Comment: either you are out of physical memory (as Cris said) or you are out of free contiguous memory (which is probably greengrass62's error). MATLAB stores variables in a free slot in RAM of the same size as your variable. If such a slot is not available anymore, it raises an error. So reboot your computer once in a while before you buy more physical memory